# https proxy for GAE dev server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, nginx, https, proxy

I'm developing app for GAE. Currently GAE dev server doesn't support https, so I managed to create a HTTPS proxy using nginx. The problem is that I also have a third party service that uses my app, but only can make requests using HTTPS, i.e. it can make request https://localhost, but won't proceed http://localhost. Inside my app I use the library of the service that internally uses req.getRequestURL() from HttpServletRequest. So, the request: Request (to https: //localhost) -> nginx proxy -> Request (to http: //localhost) -> dev GAE server. And req.getRequestURL() returns "http: //localhost" which doesn't match that in the request field (it's a special field in the request specified by the protocol of the service) and the library throws exception. What can I do? 
My nginx config:

```
 server {       
   listen              443 ssl; # The ssl directive tells NGINX to decrypt 
                                # the traffic
   server_name         localhost;
   ssl_certificate     ls.crt; # This is the certificate file
   ssl_certificate_key ls.key; # This is the private key file
   location / {     
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;       
   }
}
```

Comment: nginx should set `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` in the header (I guess), and the server can use it to determine that the original request (from client) is https.

Comment: I can see the header by req.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto") but unfortunately it has no influence on req.getRequestURL() (((

Comment: you either do some hacking yourself:) or ask the author to fix this "bug".

Comment: Ok, I think I found something, <Set name="forwarded">true</Set> is a parameter to Jetty's config (GAE uses Jetty). How can I "transfer" this one to Jetty through GAE dev server?

Comment: OK, ok done it by using servlet Filter + HttpServletRequestWrapper. It's ugly but works for testing purposes)